# JAXB XML adapters not used with type of XmlElements annotation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class A, with subclasses B and C.
Furthermore I am using the XmlJavaTypeAdapters annotation in the package-info.java file. In it I am specifying adapters for B and C

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = BAdapter.class, type = B.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = CAdapter.class, type = C.class)
})
package xyz;
```

In a class in package xyz that is to be serialized with JAXB I am writing this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "entries")
@XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "b-entry", type = B.class),
               @XmlElement(name = "c-entry", type = C.class) })
private List<A> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

This construct in general always works when not requiring XML adapters. However, now, it seems to be that JAXB is not using the defined XML adapters for the @XmlElement types. It is trying to serialize "b-entry" and "c-entry" without the adapters, which fails.
I have many other XmlAdapters on package level, they all work unless you use them with @XmlElements.

Is this a bug or a shortcoming of JAXB? Is my approach wrong?

Please note that I have to use the package level annotation, I cannot annotate directly in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it is indeed impossible to use `@XmlElements` together with package level XML adapters or possibly any XML adapter.

I worked around the issue by creating a `List<B>` as well as a `List<C>` and then later in code combining them to form a `List<A>`.

What is most important however for XML adapters to work with list elements: You are not allowed to specify the `type` attribute of `@XmlElement`. Leave it out and the XML adapter will work. This means, the type argument of the List has to be the exact type for which you have the adapter.